# No response of button in headerView of UITabView

Tags: ios

I creat a ViewController with a tabView use xib,and I add a button in headerView of the tabView.But when I click the button,no response.Check out the userInterfaceEnabled is ture.Why?

Comment: Have you connected your button with the `IBAction` method?

Comment: yeah,use the xib directly,but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're connecting your button to the actual code using an IBOutlet property in your header file. A good explanation on where to click can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html).

Once it's hooked up, in your view controller assign it some kind of function by giving it a target.
This can be done by calling this in your viewDidLoad method in your viewController. Here you want the "yourButtonName" to match whatever you named the button in your header file.

```
[yourButtonName addTarget:self action:@selector(yourFunctionName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Finally give the "yourFunctionName" something to do.

```
-(void)yourFunctionName{
    //do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it's about the height property of tabView using xib.It's all right when I don't use the xib.

Answer (score 0):

I'v got a solution:set the height of the headerView in tabView.But a confusion appeared:the headerView is displayed without a height setting,and it's not interactive.Only in setting case,can it working.